# CSS Button has a border

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to define a custom css button for my search form.  I cant figure out why this particular button has a strange border around it?  I need to get it removed but cannot figure out where it is coming from within the css..code and fiddle below.

```
/* Define Search Button */
button.button-search::-moz-focus-inner { padding:0; border:0; } /* FF Fix */
button.button-search { -webkit-border-fit:lines; } /* <- Safari & Google Chrome Fix */
button.button-search { position:absolute; right:10px; top:8px; } 
button.button-search > span { 
    background: #3399CC; /* Old browsers */
    box-shadow:1px 1px 0 #a4a4a4; 
    display:block;
    float:none;
    width:88px; 
    height:32px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    text-align:center; 
    font-size:15px; 
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center !important;
}

button.button-search span span { padding:0; float:none; }

button.button-search:hover > span { 
    opacity:0.8 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=80) !important;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 0 #a4a4a4;
}

.header .form-search button.button-search { } 
.header .form-search button.button-search > span { }
.header .form-search button.button-search:hover > span { }
.header .form-search button.button-search span span { }
.header .form-search button.button-search:hover span {}

<div class="header">
  <div class="form-search">
      <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button-search"><span><span>Search</span></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fnysccad/

Thanks

Comment: you are applying the css to a span inside the button...

Comment: It's coming from the default styling of `button`, but I'm not sure how to fix it. You might consider using an element other than `button` for this, e.g. `a`.

Comment: Why using a button whereas you can use `<a>` ?

Comment: @Jacob is correct-- see http://jsfiddle.net/fnysccad/2/ Simply apply the CSS directly to the `button` and set `border: none;`

Comment: @kgh the correct way would be `border:none;` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the CSS to the spans inside the button, so the default styling for the button is still being used:

Get rid of all the messy `<span>`, and, as @Christoph said in the comments, `type="submit"` can be omitted, as it is the default functionality of a button:

```
<div class="form-search">

<button title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button-search">Search</button>
</div>
```

Apply the CSS to the input:

```
button.button-search::-moz-focus-inner { padding:0; border:0; } /* FF Fix */
button.button-search { -webkit-border-fit:lines; } /* <- Safari & Google Chrome Fix */
button.button-search { position:absolute; right:10px; top:8px; } 
button.button-search { 
    background: #3399CC; /* Old browsers */
    box-shadow:1px 1px 0 #a4a4a4; 
    display:block;
    float:none;
    width:88px; 
    height:32px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    text-align:center; 
    font-size:15px; 
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center !important;
    border:none;/*Removes the border*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3t2srfg/1/

Comment: Button is a perfectly fine use here. After all, that's what a button is supposed to do. However, he could omit the type, since `submit` is the default action of a button. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: Great answer.  Worked perfectly, modifying a template - not sure why all those spans are there?  Any thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Those spans look like the sort of thing left as artifacts of WYSIWYG editing in a CMS. Is that what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Button has border, and background by default.

Remove them, and will be good.

But i dont think its valid to add span into button.

Solution is here: (css)

```
button.button-search { background: transparent; border: none; position:absolute; right:10px; top:8px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following code above your code, it will work:

```
button {
        border: medium none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
```

This code reset some of the default styles in the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of default style you need to override it by define your own class for example 'change':-

```
 <button  type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button-search change"><span><span>Search</span></span></button>

button.button-search.change{
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Updated fiddle :-http://jsfiddle.net/ynwypqw2/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like solutions requiring a different html structure work for you. But to answer the original question, here's the css solution for getting a `button` to respect your custom styles:

```
button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

This tells Safari and Chrome (webkit), Firefox (moz), and standards-compliant browsers to not enforce their default `button` styles, and then makes sure there's no padding or border.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like this, if i understood your question:

```
.button-search{border:0px;background-color:inherit;}
.button-search:focus{outline:none;}
```

Answer (score -3):

use this `.button-search{ border: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: so you can use this
 .button-search{
     border: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

Comment: Not really, his problem was the border, not the margin, and defiantly not the padding. Even if he did need the, inline styles are NOT the way to do it!

Comment: ohh I ma sorry I made it border